# how to determine the relative differences in activity between metals

Tags: electrochemistry

I am doing a lab for school and I do not know what this question is asking. In this lab we are making electrochemical cells from different metals.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Could you provide a little more detail in your question? What exactly are you supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have a standard pot of liquid electrolyte into which are dipped non-touching same-spaced paired strips of different clean metals.  The external circuit between the strips is a sensitive voltmeter (with extremely high electrical resistance - hard by zero current flow).  You measure the potential (noting direction!) between all combinations of paired strips, (n)(n-1)/2, and then draw certain conclusions.

Why are amalgams saturated with respect to excess solid metal interesting substrates for this experiment (e.g., aluminum)? How do you construct a standard hydrogen electrode?